# Level of detail of the google analytics extract in TABLEAU

Tags: google-analytics, tableau-api

Wondering if someone knows what is the level of detail of an GA extract in TABLEAU
It brings the data by user id or aggregates the data by date?

10x!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be programing related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are connecting to Google Analytics.

If you are connecting directly from Tableau to Google Analytics, you will be able to filter the data to keep under the 10k row limits, as described in [How to Connect Tableau and Google Analytics](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/10/28/how-to-connect-tableau-and-google-analytics/)

If you use a premium version of Google Analytics along with BigQuery before Tableau, there are no limits and you receive each event at the lowest grain

Comment: 10x! this is exactly what I was looking for